# Move a bunch of ical events at once

Tags: ical

I have got all the dates and times for my class seminars set in iCal, and I've also made week-long events that coincide with my colleges week numbering.

The thing is, I forgot to let out this Easter holidays, which are two weeks that should be blank.

What I want to do is select all events and move them two weeks. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iCal cannot do this by itself unfortunately.  There is a $8 shareware program called [Calibrate](http://www.woodenbrain.com/products/calibrate/calibrate.html) that can do bulk moves of iCal events.  There is a trial period to ensure it does what you want.

Comment: As of 2023, the last release was 2014. Not sure this still works. And developer's website doesn't seem to provide a download link.

Answer (score 4):

Fast forward 7 years! iCal is now Apple Calendar.

You can now select multiple events and use the keyboard shortcuts:

<kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd> [ <kbd>↑</kbd> | <kbd>↓</kbd> ] to move the events 15min sooner or later (in day/week view) or 1 week (in month view).

<kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd> [ <kbd>←</kbd> | <kbd>→</kbd> ] to move the events 1 day (in day, week & month views).

*Events must all be visible - e.g. in day view you can only simultaneously move events that are in Today.*

Comment: and for what it’s worth, this shortcut worked in the days of iCal too!

Answer (score 0):

#### Coarse Solution Using macOS Calendar alone: Use "Select All" in Month View

1. Hide calendars you don't want to edit.
2. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (Week View)
3. *Recommended:* Select one of the events you want to edit so the next step focuses on that time period.
4. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (Month View)
5. *The Fussy Part:* Scroll to time period which shows only the events you want to edit.
6. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (Select All)
7. *Optional step if you want to adjust event **time**:* <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (Week View)
8. <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd> (<- this key may be unnecessary), <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> (shift event dates or times)

#### Accurate Solution Using Apple Shortcuts

1. Create a new Shortcut
2. **Add Action: "Find Calendar Events"** and adjust settings
3. *Optional:* Add the following Actions if you want to be safe:

   - "Show Result"
   - "Stop This Shortcut"
4. **Add Action: "Adjust Date"** and adjust settings