# Drag-and-drop multiple events in Calendar

Tags: keyboard, calendar, ical

This question is primarily for macOS, but if someone have an answer for iOS (iPhone and iPad) it'd be lovely too.

So, I want to move multiple events at once. I saw [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12966/move-a-bunch-of-ical-events-at-once) that it's possible by keyboard shortcut. However, this solution is slow as it's moving by small steps of 15 minutes, or 1 day.

Is it possible to simple select multiple events (eg by command+click), and then to simple click one of them (probably together with unknown keys in keyboard) to drag-and-drop the bunch of events at once accurately with the mouse pointer or trackpad?

Or, this feature is missing and the pointing is possible only by keyboard arrows and not mouse/trackpad (together with keyboard presses simultaneously), do you have better offer that the suggested in the link above?

Comment: The linked answer was incorrect [I've fixed it] - you can move a week at a time in month view.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to *select* specific events and then to move them together. In Month View, is it possible to gather specific events, or we have to move the whole week? In addition, what about Week View? Day View? thanks!

Comment: The only available options are what is set out in that answer.